# How to use results from different isolates in the main isolate?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I'm really new to Dart and also to programming. I'm trying to develop a a **command-line** program in Dart using isolates. My intention is to compare it's performance againt the same program, but written in Java with threads.

The Dart program looks like this so far:

1. main.dart

   ```
   import "dart:async";
   import "dart:isolate";

   main() {    
       var rPort1 = new ReceivePort();
       var rPort2 = new ReceivePort();

       var p1 = 0;
       rPort1.listen((partial) {
           print("p1 ${partial}");
           p1 = partial;
           rPort1.close();
       });
       var p2 = 0;
       rPort2.listen((partial) {
          print("p2 ${partial}");
          p2 = partial;
          rPort2.close();
       });

       Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("MyIsolate.dart"), [arg0, ...], rPort1.sendPort);
       Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("MyIsolate.dart"), [arg0, ...], rPort2.sendPort);

       var p3 = p1 + p2;
       print("p3 ${p3}");
   }
   ```
2. myIsolate.dart

   ```
   import "dart:async";
   import "dart:isolate";

   main(args, SendPort port) {
       var partial = 0;
       // ... do stuff ...
       // args are used and partial is updated
       port.send(partial);
   }
   ```

The output looks like this:

```
p3 0
p1 -0.1168096561671553
p2 0.023709338284264223
```

As you can see the return values of each **isolate** comes after the **main isolate** has finished it's execution. What I want is to use the result of the isolates to further calculation in the main.

I don't know what I'm missing. I'm sure is something very stupid, but I cannot move forward on this problem. In Java is simple to get the result value of each thread, but in Dart I can't figure how to do this in isolates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You have to wait until all streams (from your ports) are complete. One of ways for doing that is something like that:

```
import "dart:async";
import "dart:isolate";

main() {
  var rPort1 = new ReceivePort();
  var rPort2 = new ReceivePort();

  // Defining completers which would complete when Streams are finished   
  Completer c1 = new Completer();
  Completer c2 = new Completer();

  var p1 = 0;
  rPort1.listen((partial) {
    print("p1 ${partial}");
    p1 = partial;
    rPort1.close();
  }, onDone: ()=>c1.complete()); // Notice onDone callback here
  var p2 = 0;
  rPort2.listen((partial) {
    print("p2 ${partial}");
    p2 = partial;
    rPort2.close();

  }, onDone: ()=>c2.complete()); // And here

  Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("my_isolate.dart"), [0], rPort1.sendPort);
  Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("my_isolate.dart"), [0], rPort2.sendPort);

  // Waiting for both streams to complete before summing our results
  Future.wait([c1.future,c2.future]).then((_){
    var p3 = p1 + p2;
    print("p3 ${p3}");
  });
}
```

For your task, if you're waiting for exact values, you may define only Futures for these values you need, and complete them without waiting for your isolates (and their streams) to finish.

For doing this, just move `c*.complete(<value>)` to corresponding listen() callback. Something like that (not tested):

```
rPort1.listen((partial) {
  print("p1 ${partial}");
  c1.complete(partial);
  rPort1.close();
});
rPort2.listen((partial) {
  print("p2 ${partial}");
  c2.complete(partial);
  rPort2.close();
});

...

Future.wait([c1.future,c2.future]).then((result){
  var p3 = result[0] + result[1];
  print("p3 ${p3}");
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Mike! That was just what I was looking for. I tested hehre and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: On that last part `Future.wait([c1.future,c2.future]).then((_){ ... });` I also added a **await** expression, which let's me continue the execution in the main isolate as if I was running it synchronously. So the final code looks like this: `await Future.wait([c1.future,c2.future]).then((_){ ... });`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot to put `await` or `.then()` there. By the way, you need only one of them,  not both. You may use `await` and then put dependent code after it, or use `.then()` without `await`, because they are doing almost the same thing, only error handling differs a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for something in Dart, that something should be a future. You can convert a stream or port event to a future in many different ways. If in doubt, you can always use a `Completer` to create a future from any other event.
In this case it can be done easier because you just want one event from each stream, and you can use `Stream.first` (or `Stream.last` or `Stream.single`) for that.

```dart
import "dart:async";
import "dart:isolate";

main() {
  var rPort1 = new ReceivePort();
  var rPort2 = new ReceivePort();

  Future.wait([
      Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("my_isolate.dart"), ["0"], rPort1.sendPort)
             .then((_) => rPort1.first,
                   onError: (_) => rPort1.close()),
      Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("my_isolate.dart"), ["0"], rPort2.sendPort)
             .then((_) => rPort2.first,
                   onError: (_) => rPort2.close()),
  ]).then((ps) {
     // Waiting for both streams to complete before summing our results
     var p3 = ps[0] + ps[1];
     print("p3 ${p3}");
  });
}
```

Here I also wait for the `spawnUri` return `Future` because it may contain an error if your isolate didn't spawn correctly.

You can also use some of the helper functions in the isolate package.

```dart
import "dart:async";
import "dart:isolate";
import "package:isolate/isolate.dart";

main() async {
  // A SingleResponseChannel has a send-port and a result future,
  // and completes the future with the first port event.
  // Warning: Only closed when event is sent on port!
  // Consider setting a time-out on the channel.
  var c1 = new SingleResponseChannel();
  var c2 = new SingleResponseChannel();
  Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("my_isolate.dart"), ["0"], c1.port);
  Isolate.spawnUri(new Uri.file("my_isolate.dart"), ["0"], c2.port);
  var p3 = await c1.result + await c2.result;
  print("p3 ${p3}");
}
```

Comment: Had to change `[0]` to `['0']` for these two examples compile. Also the second example which uses the helper `isolate package` needs `isolate: ^2.0.3` in your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Good catch. The argument list does need to be a list of strings. Fixing that.